# Netsuite saved search extract first six characters

Tags: netsuite, saved-searches

I'm trying to extract first six characters from a field using NetSuite saved search expression.
Example if the field "DCBB18-271-LG" I want the result to only display "DCBB18"

Thanks!

Imran

Comment: You say you're trying ... how exactly? If by trying you mean "asking on stack overflow" then that isn't trying, that's asking for some code monkey to write code for you :p

Comment: I've tried using substr and instr functions based on the NetSuite help docs, but so far not having success. If you're able to guide, that would be much appreciated. I'm trying to learn here, and not just asking for others do it for me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should be able to use the `SUBSTR` expression within a `Formula (Text)` Result column to accomplish this.

For example, if you wanted the first six characters of the field `{upccode}`, then your formula would look like:

```
SUBSTR({upccode}, 0, 6)
```

You can check out the other SQL functions you can use in formulae by checking the NetSuite Help page titled `SQL Expressions`.

HTH

Comment: Thank you! Really appropriate the assist. I was trying to run it for external ID field and the syntax worked perfectly. Also, thanks for suggestion on SQL expression help page.